# Colon problems in BibLaTeX citation style

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, footnotes, citing

I have to use the bibliography entry for the first citation of a source. This bibliography string contains several colons which are unfortunately not visible in the footnote. The following minimal example is supposed to be a showcase for that problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

% Bibliography database
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Knu86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = {1986},
    title = {The \TeX book},
    publisher = {publisher},
    location = {location},
  }
\end{filecontents}

% Biblography style
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bbx}
    \ProvidesFile{\jobname.bbx}
    \RequireBibliographyStyle{standard}

    \renewcommand*{\newblockpunct}{\addcolon\space}

    \DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{
    \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
    \usebibmacro{author}
    \addspace
    \printfield[parens]{year}
    \newblock
    \printfield{title}
    \newunit
    \printlist{location}
    \newblock
    \printlist{publisher}
    }
    \endinput
\end{filecontents}

% Citation style
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.cbx}
    \ProvidesFile{\jobname.cbx}
    \RequireCitationStyle{verbose}

    \renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
    \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
    \printtext[bibhypertarget]
        { \usedriver{}{\thefield{entrytype}}}
    }
    \endinput
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex8,citestyle=\jobname,bibstyle=\jobname]{biblatex}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citepages=omit,citetracker=true,labelyear}
\bibliography{\jobname}


\begin{document}
\null\vfill\noindent
Filler text \footcite[85]{Knu86}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Why is the bibliography not fully copied? A first guess of mine would be that the `\newblockpunct` command is executed correctly only in the bibliography style. But how do I transform it to the citation style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full citations are generated by `\usedriver`, whose internal definition invokes:

```
\let\newblock\relax
```

To avoid this, you can add the following to your preamble.

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\blx@imc@usedriver}{\let\newblock\relax}{}{}{}
\makeatother
```

However the block delimiter `\newblockpunct` is intended to delimit larger segments of the bibliography entry. Default values correspond to some form of whitespace specified by the `block` option setting. In your custom drivers you might be better off using `\setunit{\addcolon\space}`.

Comment: The alternative you suggested works perfectly well. However, by redefining the `\newblockpunct` delimiter I intended to avoid writing every time the long form with `\setunit`. But I think I can define a completey new command for this, can't I?

Comment: `\newblock` is not equivalent to `\setunit{\newblockpunct}`. To delimit fields you should use `\newunit`, `\setunit{<punctuation commands>}` or `\setunit*{<punctuation commands>}`. You can define commands based on these, but I don't see how these could be more clear/much shorter.

Comment: I see, the first sentence of your last comment is the solution I was looking for.